# Why doesn't identity in network settings reflect my spoofed MAC address?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have installed `macchanger` and been using it for a little while now just fine. For example, this is what happens when I do the following...

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 down
$ sudo macchanger -r wlp1s0
Current MAC:   6e:cf:be:d5:23:1a (unknown)
Permanent MAC: 6e:cf:be:d5:23:1a (unknown)
New MAC:       72:c1:b1:ee:a5:a7 (unknown)
$ sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up
$ ifconfig
...
wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet X.X.X.X  netmask X.X.X.X  broadcast X.X.X.X
        ether 72:c1:b1:ee:a5:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1112465  bytes 1447940135 (1.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 554071  bytes 64267231 (61.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It seems to work as expected. However, I recently stumbled across my permanent MAC address saved as an Identity for a WiFi network I connect to, as can be seen here:

[image]

You can get to this tab by clicking in the top right of the desktop, selecting WiFi settings from the WiFi dropdown, then clicking the gear icon next to the WiFi network you are connected to.

**Despite my MAC address showing as changed in the command line and in the details tab, in the identity tab the MAC is still my permanent MAC.**

My question is, why is the MAC not changing here? Is my MAC actually changed, or is the WiFi card caching my permanent MAC and using it to identify with the network? I have a feeling that this is just an issue where the GUI doesn't update properly, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: You can log into your modem to confirm your MAC address.
You can also use Wireshark to check the handshake between your desktop computer and your modem. Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) resolves your MAC address. It may take a minute or two for the handshake to repeat.